# Social login or Third party login in IBM mobile first 7.1 app

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

**Problem statement:**
Am trying to implement a third party login( which is oauth based) in IBM mobile first 7.1 mobile app.

In my login screen , users clicks on a social login button(ex: FB, Gmail or third party login). User redirects to login screen in chrome custom tab and after login user will be redirected to my app where am asking for local mobile app credentials which is used to display some service based on local credentials.

Normal login with my local credentials works fine. But i come back to my app after oauth authentication, am entering my local credentials and trying to call an adapter where it sets the activeuser ( WL.server.setActiveUser("relamname","useridentity")). with that details. It fails with this exception in developer tools.

**Exception :**
data from invocation ::{"responseHeaders":{"X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","P3P":"policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","Expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Pragma":"no-cache","Content-Length":"655","Date":"Sat, 20 Oct 2018 19:22:23 GMT"},"status":200,"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"reference\":{\"rhinoException\":\"org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException (\/integration.js#44)\",\"fileName\":\"\/integration.js\",\"stack\":\"\tat \/integration.js:44 (anonymous)\r\n\tat 2018-10-16T15:49:01.934Z\/291f5a76b4dfb3b0c62ecbf35ab7ac3a62b0b204\/Authentication_sso-impl.js:119 (login_sso)\r\n\",\"name\":\"JavaException\",\"message\":\"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException: null\",\"lineNumber\":44,\"javaException\":\"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException\"},\"errorCode\":\"100\",\"isSuccessful\":true,\"authStatus\":\"credentialsRequired\"}*/","responseJSON":{"reference":{"rhinoException":"org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException (/integration.js#44)","fileName":"/integration.js","stack":"\tat /integration.js:44 (anonymous)\r\n\tat 2018-10-16T15:49:01.934Z/291f5a76b4dfb3b0c62ecbf35ab7ac3a62b0b204/Authentication_sso-impl.js:119 (login_sso)\r\n","name":"JavaException","message":"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException: null","lineNumber":44,"javaException":"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException"},"errorCode":"100","isSuccessful":true,"authStatus":"credentialsRequired"},"errorCode":"100","invocationContext":null,"invocationResult":{"reference":{"rhinoException":"org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException (/integration.js#44)","fileName":"/integration.js","stack":"\tat /integration.js:44 (anonymous)\r\n\tat 2018-10-16T15:49:01.934Z/291f5a76b4dfb3b0c62ecbf35ab7ac3a62b0b204/Authentication_sso-impl.js:119 (login_sso)\r\n","name":"JavaException","message":"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException: null","lineNumber":44,"javaException":"com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException"},"errorCode":"100","isSuccessful":true,"authStatus":"credentialsRequired"}}

**My Question :**
Can we do social login in IBM mobile first 7.1, Is this the problem with challange handlers, Do I need to create a new challange handler if i want to login in different screen other than login screen?

Can we create multiple challange hanlders for single auth realm?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did some one understand the question, if yes please post your ideas or views

Comment: Join this slack channel there are bunch of MobileFirst developers who might help you https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/05/26/come-chat-with-us/

Comment: The response from the adapter shows ""authStatus\":\"credentialsRequired\"". This means, the application is being challenged by the server. This can be handled in the challenge handler. But if this is happening after you have successfully logged in, then your flow might not be sending the token / authstatus to the server. A network traffic capture will give more idea on whats happening and whats not